# Prevent HTML text to distort clickable overlay

Tags: html, css

For my website to allow file uploads I created a droparea where people can either drag & drop multiple files to upload or click on the area to upload a single file from disk. For this, I have a file input which is hidden acting as an overlay for the droparea.

My problem is that the p-tag takes up some space within the droparea which makes it not clickable anymore but lets your select the p-tag text instead. Any ideas how to make the p-tag non-selectable and trigger the click event even if you directly click on the p-tag text?

My code looks as follows:

```html
<div class="droparea">
  <input type="file" id="upload_input" name="upload"/>
  <p>Drop here or click to select from disk</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.droparea {
   width: 30%;
   height: 100px;
   border-style: dashed;
   border-width: 3px;
   border-color: blue;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: calc(8px + 1vw);
}

.droparea input {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   font-size: 40px;
   opacity: 0;
   filter:alpha(opacity=0);
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.droparea p {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
    padding: 0px 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one possible solution for this with pure css is `pointer-events: none;`

```
.droparea p {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

> The pointer-events CSS property specifies under what circumstances (if
>   any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse
>   events.

For better browser support you can use this two polyfill

1. https://github.com/jquery/PEP
2. https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. Thanks. Will accept the answer as soon as the required timespan has reached